# Is it possible for clingo to output which facts/rules are used in generating a solution?

Tags: clingo

Is it possible for clingo to output which facts/rules are used in generating a solution?

As an simple example, the following code can be used to show that Socrates is mortal:

```
man(socrates).       % socrates is a man
mortal(X) :- man(X). % all men are mortal

greek(socrates).     % other info not needed for question


% is socrates mortal?
#show.
#show "Yes" : mortal(socrates).
```

Which produces:

```
clingo version 5.6.2 (d469780)
Reading from test.cl
Solving...
Answer: 1
"Yes"
SATISFIABLE

Models       : 1
Calls        : 1
Time         : 0.002s (Solving: 0.00s 1st Model: 0.00s Unsat: 0.00s)
CPU Time     : 0.000s
```

Is it possible to also get access to the facts/rules which were used in finding the "Yes" solution e.g. `mortal(X) :- man(X).` and `man(socrates).` (but not `greek(socrates).` and any other facts/rules which may have been specified but not needed for the found solution).

EDIT: I know if I omit the #show and add `is_socrates_mortal :- mortal(socrates).` It produces the whole answer set e.g. `man(socrates) mortal(socrates) is_socrates_mortal greek(socrates)`. But in that case it also gives `greek(socrates)` which isn't needed for the ordinal question "is socrates mortal?".

I'd like to get access to specifically the facts/rules needed in producing a given solution.

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in feature for this. Do you need a generic solution or are you happy with a modified version of your program?

Comment: Also, what do you expect to have as output in case multiple explanations are available for the "Yes" answer?

Comment: @logi-kal - Overall I'm looking for a generic solution, but might be able to work that out from a specific example if you don't mind posting a modified version of my program. Just getting access to one way of it being true would be of use to me, but if it were able show all possible explanations that would be even better.

Comment: Can a question be only _ground_ or it may also contain variables (like `mom(socrates,X)` for "did Socrates have a mom?")?.

Comment: The overall aim is to include variables - but if this cannot be done, only ground questions would still be useful - thanks for your time with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else comes across this.

There is a project called xclingo2 which does what I was after:

https://github.com/bramucas/xclingo2

For the input:

```
%!trace_rule {"socrates is a man"}
man(socrates).

%!trace_rule {"All men are mortal"}
mortal(X) :- man(X). 

%!trace_rule {"socrates is greek"}
greek(socrates).


%!show_trace mortal(socrates).
```

I get:

```
Answer 1
  *
  |__All men are mortal
  |  |__socrates is a man
```

Answer (score 0):

Clingo, which is part of the ASP (Answer Set Programming) system, typically provides the set of rules and facts that are used in generating a solution. In ASP, a solution corresponds to an answer set, which is a consistent set of literals that satisfies the rules and constraints specified in the program.

When you run Clingo, it usually outputs the answer sets along with the rules

Comment: If you know how I'd be interested. If I run `clingo test.cl` where test.cl contains the example program I gave, I get the output I posted (less CPU time etc - now added)